# UIPinchGestureRecognizer not responding

Tags: iphone, ios, gesture, pinch

I have a universal binary application and currently working on the iPad version of the application. The iPad is using a uitabbarcontroller and on the second tab I have 6 images and when adding a UIPinchGesture it is not responding. I have `userInteractionEnabled=YES;` I tried adding the image view programmatically and then adding the gesture recognizer and still nothing seems to work.

I tried setting the delegate to the view controller and implementing one of the delegate methods and didn't get any responses. Below is the code sample of what I am doing:

```
UIImageView *img2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2-large.png"]];
img2.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);
[img2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
img2.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.view addSubview:img2];    

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *img2Pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(img2Pinch:)];
[img2 addGestureRecognizer:img2Pinch];
[img2Pinch release];


- (void)img2Pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender {
      NSLog(@"HERE");
}
```

I'm sure it's something silly that I'm missing. I've used this stuff before but can't for the life of me figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: i solved my own problem apparently somehow I managed to accidentally turn of user interaction enabled for my view in interface builder. -1 for stupidity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`. The default is `NO`. Also, in order to handle multi-touches, which is what the pinch is, `multipleTouchEnabled` needs to be set to `YES`.

Comment: Wasn't able to get this to work, I have even tried using UITapGestureRecognizer. Any other ideas?

img2.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
img2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *img2Pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(img2Pinch:)];
[img2 addGestureRecognizer:img2Pinch];
[img2Pinch release];

Comment: Try setting canBecomeFirstResponder to YES.

Comment: I solved my own problem apparently somehow I managed to accidentally turn of user interaction enabled for my view in interface builder. -1 for stupidity

Answer (score 0):

What view are you placing it into?
Is it a scroll view?

Also `img2.multipleTouchEnabled = YES`, multi touch is not enabled by default, a pinch requires multiple fingers.

(`img2Pinch` is correctly released)